# Facebook login on page - what when user delete app in own account?

Tags: facebook, authentication, account

I added Facebook Login on my website.

All is OK, but this is one situation what I afraid.

User register account on my page via Facebook Login. He can login on my website by Facebook Login. User is logged on my website and at the same time he delete my app in own account on facebook.com.

What now? How I can check that user have still my app on his account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming by "still have my app on his account" you mean your app is still authorized to access that user's account with whatever permissions you've requested/the user granted when signing onto your site.

If you've followed Facebook's instructions on implementing Facebook Login for Web on your site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/) you are probably already set to handle user revoking FB permissions from your app (or deleting your app from those allowed access to his/her account). Basically, when a user accesses your site and uses Facebook login you send a request to FB API to check their current login status:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#checklogin

and if the returned result indicates that they are, in fact, logged in to Facebook but not your app you need to ask them to authorize your application (pretty much follow the same flow as the first time they signup for your site with Facebook Login excluding the part of creating a new account on your site for them):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#login

which would add it back to their account until deleted again. Remember to update your auth tokens for that user when they re-authorize your app.

----Edit---

Are you using PHP SDK library provided by Facebook or your own? In either case you should be storing user's login status in your app as well as the access token that you received from FB. 
You need to use these every time a user accesses your site (just like any other site that requires user authentication logic).

These are FB instructions on checking user's login status:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/

Here's a quick code redux (using Facebook's PHP SDK library) that works for my apps (with error handling removed for code brevity/clarity). The Facebook PHP SDK library is loaded into

```
$this->facebook
```

prior to the function code below.

```
    function facebook_login(){     
      $user = (int)$this->facebook->getUser();
     /*the above line will get you either facebook user id in case of user being already logged in to Facebook and your app or 0 otherwise*/
      if($user){
        if(!$this->have_access_token(/*...*/)){
          /* if you don't have user's FB access token in local storage you need to obtain and set it now */
          $this->facebook->setExtendedAccessToken(); // Get a long-lived access token
          $userAccessToken = $this->facebook->getAccessToken(); // Set the user's access token
          $this->save_access_token('access_token', $userAccessToken); // Store to prevent unnecessary API calls
         } else {
            $userAccessToken = $this->get_user_access_token(/*...*/); // Set the user's access token from local app storage            
         }  
        if (!empty($userAccessToken)) {
          /*the $user variable now contains facebook_id of the current user
            you can do whatever else you need with it at this point
          */
        }


    } else {
       // The user has not been authenticated--generate a new login url and show FB login dialogue
       $fbLoginParams = array(
           'scope' => '[your permissions requirements here]',
           'redirect_uri' => '[your redirect url here]'
        );
       $login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($fbLoginParams);
       header("Location: " . $login_url);
    }

  }
```

If for whatever reason you wrote your own library you can probably devise similar functionality from the FB instructions, the code snippet above, and definitely take a look at the functions used in the code above in Facebook's PHP lib.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replay. I use PHP API. 
Yes, I mean that my app is still authorized to access that user's account.

To render login button I use XFBML.

This is any way to check this by PHP API?

Thanks.

Comment: I use PHP SDK by Facebook.

Comment: I use this SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Situation like this:
User is logged on my site via Facebook Login. User delete my app from his account. My app doesn't have auth in right now.

But code:

    require_once 'fb_src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook();
    $fb_user = $facebook->getUser();
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
   var_dump($fb_user.$access_token);

still show me the correct user's ID and Access Token.. Why? How i can check my app's auth?

Comment: Oh, now i undestend how it's work :)
How long i have to stroing access token? Like a session?

Comment: Hmm..
One more question :)

This function perform only when user click facebook login button, yes?
Or every website refresh?

Comment: How does your website authentication work? Do you just ask them once to allow your app access to their account and that's all? What's the purpose of the FB authentication in the first place? You could probably just store something in session to indicate they've logged in to your site via fb and whenever a user comes to your site check for that session variable. You should expire it once in a while probably or depending on how old the session is re-check the access token validity (instead of having the login button).